# Storing Dynamic Data in Excel Fields

Tags: excel

I have a command that returns the number of groups a user belongs to in AWS. The number of groups that a user can belong to can vary.

I want to store this data in excel with each user having a list of groups next to his name. I want each group to have it's own field. But the number of groups may vary.

For example, the following users all have different numbers of groups:

```
aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name tdunphy --profile=company-prod  | jq -r  '.Groups[].GroupName'
grp-quicksight
agility-admin
grp-account-bill
grp-sag
grp-flow-log-user
company_SAG
grp-cloud-formation
grp-cloudops


aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name broberts  --profile=company-prod  | jq -r  '.Groups[].GroupName'
agility-admin
grp-account-bill
grp-sag
grp-cloud-formation
grp-cloudops


aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name ejimenez  --profile=company-prod  | jq -r  '.Groups[].GroupName'
agility-admin
grp-cloudops
```

Ideally I would like to display this data horizontally like so:

```
User Name  Groups
tdunphy    grp-quicksight agility-admin    grp-account-bill grp-sag (etc)
broberts   agility-admin  grp-account-bill grp-sag          grp-cloud-formation
```

Each group name should be in it's own column. But I'm not sure it would look neat this way. I am open to listing the group names horizontally if that would look better.

I'll be dumping the group names from an AWS command into a text file. And then dumping that text file into a CSV programmatically.

How can I store each list of groups for each user, with each group getting it's own field? I won't be able to predict how many groups a user will belong to. Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to display the results vertically or horizontally? Will your data be in a separate file or, perhaps, in a column of data in an existing workbook?

Comment: Oops. What I should have asked is for you to show us the preferred layout based on the data shown above. That'll make it easy to work out how to structure the solution.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz! I've just updated the OP to try and answer your questions. Let me know if I need to clarify further. Thanks!

Comment: I think this just comes down to a matter of opinion. Personally I would store this as ` user | group ` with the user repeated down the rows next to each group they belong to. It would be like a proper table that way that could be pivoted, or eventually migrated to a proper database.

Comment: @bluethundr Thanks. What was your conclusion about the format - user|group vs group|user? Would you actually prefer the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code generates the following data.
[image]
There are a couple of assumptions.

- the AWS raw data is in a sheet called "aws_input" (though this is a  variable).
- this data is in column A and starts in row 1
- the output is created in a sheet called "aws_output" (this is a variable too)
- the output begins in row2 of Column A. This allows cell A1 to have a header, say, "User Name".

---

```
Sub BuildAWSGroups()    
Dim AWSPrefix As Long, FindName As Long, NextFree As Long, LastFree As Long, EndRow As Long, runningtotal As Long    
Dim UserName As String    
Dim awsrow As Long, outputrow As Long    
Dim wsi, wso As Worksheet    

' name the sheets    
Set wsi = Sheets("aws_input")    
Set wso = Sheets("aws_output")    


' length of the AWS prefix -> aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name    
AWSPrefix = 41    

'set values to all the variables    
FindName = 0    
NextFree = 0    
LastFree = 0    
EndRow = 0    
runningtotal = 0    
awsrow = 1    
outputrow = 2    

'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)    
EndRow = wsi.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    

' do stuff so long as you don't go past the last row of data    
Do While runningtotal <= EndRow    

' the last test for NextFree throws an error, so we'll look for the error    
On Error Resume Next    
' get the next non-blank row number    
NextFree = wsi.Range("a" & awsrow & ":a" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row    
' is there was an error then we need to calculate the next non-blank cell differently
If NextFree = LastFree Then
    NextFree = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
    After:=Range("a" & (LastFree + 2)), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
NextFree = awsrow + NextFree

End If

' find location of the user name in the aws data row
wsi.Activate
FindName = InStr((AWSPrefix + 1), wsi.Cells(awsrow, 1).Value, " ")
'extract the user name
UserName = Trim(Mid(wsi.Cells(awsrow, 1).Value, (AWSPrefix + 1), (FindName - AWSPrefix)))
'copy user name to output
wso.Cells(outputrow, 1).Value = UserName

' copy the aws groups for this user
wsi.Activate
wsi.Range(Cells((awsrow + 1), 1), Cells((NextFree - 1), 1)).Copy
'paste and transpose the groups to the user row on the output sheet
wso.Activate
wso.Cells(outputrow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

' update variables for the loop
LastFree = NextFree
awsrow = LastFree + 2
outputrow = outputrow + 1
runningtotal = awsrow

Loop
End Sub
```